# Lemma on uniform convergence in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I'm reading some class notes on harmonic analysis and the following lemma is used to prove that the Schwartz space is complete:

> Assume that $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq C^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ and that each sequence of partial derivatives $(\partial_j f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly to a function $g_j.$ Then $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\partial_j f= g_j$ for every $j.$

However, the lemma itself is not proven. I'd like to see a proof or a reference for one. Thanks.

Comment: When $n=1,$ this is a standard result which you can find in Rudin PMA for example. This result leads to the $n>1$ result. (Note: You are using $n$ in two different ways.)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2117828/27978 for example.

Comment: I don't see how it follows from the $n=1$ case.

Comment: For each $j$, fix the values of the other coordinates, while allowing $x_j$ to vary. For each fixed set of the other coordinates $(f_n) \subseteq C^1(\Bbb R)$, and the whole thing is just the $1D$ result. Once you've done this for every $j$, you've proven $f\in C^1(\Bbb R^d)$.